# Why did I suddenly gain 300GB on my server

Tags: centos, filesystems, disk-space-utilization, df

I've been working on my server all day, doing various things.  I know, unquestioningly (found the evidence by scrolling up in one of my terminal sessions) that I had about 900GB of space 4 hours ago.  It's been about that the last few days.

Now, I've noticed it's 1200GB.

I'm as certain as I can be that I've not accidentally (or intentionally) deleted 300GB of files.  But I'm scared.

Is there a rational explanation?

CentOS8, 4TB raid 1 NVME ext4 partition.

Thank you!

Comment: Did your log files get rotated, then compressed?

Comment: Nope, my weekly access_log is only 3GB or so.

Comment: Without more information, this is impossible to answer. You include no information about workloads, temporary files and so forth.

Comment: Agreed.  Web and database server, nginx, php, mariadb.  2GB database size.  2.5TB of JPEG files, and I don't think any of them have suddenly disappeared...

Comment: The rational explanation is that many processes use this computer. One scenario is a large unlinked file (i.e. a file without directory entry) is in use by some process, and is automatically removed when that process exits. You can't see that file with tools like `du` or `ls`, since it has no name. Tools like `lsof` can help you analyze such situations while such files exist, but after the fact, I would not know how confirm this scenario.